# Magento compass watch works only the first time

Tags: ruby, magento, compass-sass

Magento v1.9 rwd requires to use sass.

Few weeks ago, when i installed ruby and compass, the compass watching works so good. It's really a nice tool.

But today, when i install ruby193 + compass (sass) again on new environment, the compass just compile and create css at first time, and not watch any later changes of scss files.

The compass version is 1.0.1, sass is 3.4.2.

It's really a bit push for time on my project, but i have not any other choices except to restart the watch whenever i make any changes on scss. It's really a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

After some study on net, this issue looks like to being caused by the newest Sass. We know, as default, the newest Sass would always be installed when we install Compass.

We can find in the last few days, there had two new versions of sass:

```
3.4.2 August 29, 2014 (323 KB)
3.4.1 August 23, 2014 (325 KB)
3.4.0 August 19, 2014 (324 KB)
....
```

Two weeks ago, I installed 3.4.0 (i believe), it is working with Compass (version 1.0.1)

```
1.0.1 (08/19/2014)
1.0.0 (08/15/2014)
...
```

So i try to unintall the default Sass and install a earlier version of Sass. Lovely watching is working again. I love it, and hope my time can save many others.

```
gem unintall sass
gem intall sass -v=3.4.1
```

BTW, if u install the Ruby + Compass, and found it's not working at all, you have to check the config.rb. Compass watch doesn't work for i had one wrong configuration item like:

```
sass_dir = "../sass"
```

We know, on Magento v1.9 RWD, it should be

```
sass_dir = "../scss"
```